# Convert different dates in date column to rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I want to display different dates as columns from `LOGDATE` column.

Here are the details

My query:

```
select
    logdate,
    service_type, 
    service_name, 
    sum(entry_fee + repair_fee) as fees
from 
    myTable
where 
    logdate >= '2019-11-01'
    and logdate <= '2019-11-03'
group by
    logdate,
    service_type, 
    service_name
```

This query returns this result:

```
LOGDATE     SERVICE_TYPE  SERVICE_NAME  FEES
---------------------------------------------
2019-11-01  Engine        Car           150
2019-11-01  Window        Truck         200
2019-11-01  Trunk         Jeep          100
2019-11-02  Engine        Car            50
2019-11-02  Window        Truck          90
2019-11-02  Trunk         Jeep           70
2019-11-03  Engine        Car           300
2019-11-03  Window        Truck          80
2019-11-03  Trunk         Jeep           30
```

Expected output format:

```
SERVICE_TYPE  SERVICE_NAME  2019-11-01 2019-11-02  2019-11-03
--------------------------------------------------------------
Engine        Car           150        50          300
Window        Truck         200        90           80
Trunk         Jeep          100        70           30
```

I have multiple types of `SERVICE_TYPE` and `SERVICE_NAME`, not just the three sown in the sample.

How can I get my expected output? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation to pivot the data over a *fixed list* of `logdate`s:

```
select
    service_type, 
    service_name,
    sum(case when logdate = '2019-11-01' then entry_fee + repair_fee end) [2019-11-01],
    sum(case when logdate = '2019-11-02' then entry_fee + repair_fee end) [2019-11-02],
    sum(case when logdate = '2019-11-03' then entry_fee + repair_fee end) [2019-11-03]
from 
    mytable 
where 
    logdate >= '2019-11-01' and logdate <= '2019-11-03'
group by 
    service_type, service_name
```

---

You can also use SQL Server's `PIVOT` feature:

```
select
    service_type, 
    service_name,
    [2019-11-01],
    [2019-11-02],
    [2019-11-03]
from 
    mytable
where 
    logdate >= '2019-11-01' and logdate <= '2019-11-03'
pivot 
    (sum(entry_fee + repair_fee)
     for logdate in ([2019-11-01], [2019-11-02], [2019-11-03])
    )
```

Comment: What if I have more then 15 different dates then I need to write 15 different sum() statements, is there a way to handle this ? Just curious to know.

Comment: @zealous: indeed, you need to repeat the `sum()` expressions, that's how conditional aggregation works. For something more generic, you would need dynamic SQL (build a sql query as a string, then execute it), but that's a whole different beast.

Comment: Welcome @zealous!

Comment: @zealous: yes you can. I updated my answer with a query for that.